# Is there way to skip different find filter output in one query MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Is that possible to skip the first record in a document by name For eg product_detail is the collection and it has 10 documents with name apple and 10 documents in name mango can I skip the first 2 documents in each? The below query for skipping the first 2 documents in apple.

```
Query : 
db.getCollection('product_detail').find({"productInfo.name" : "apple"}).skip(2);
db.getCollection('product_detail').find({"productInfo.name" : "mango"}).skip(2);
```

Instead of two queries to skip 2 documents for "productInfo.name": "apple" and "productInfo.name": "mango" I need one Can anyone help me out?

Comment: What's wrong with doing 2 separate queries?

Comment: I have 10 more names it's looking messy

Comment: Do you need a limited rows of result for each query or for all the queries together? E.g. get 10 records with "apple", 10 records of "mango" *or* get 100 records of both "apple" and "mongo"

Comment: I have 10 records each total 20 records in each I wan to skip the first 2 records so in apple 8 record will be deleted and same in mango.

Comment: Doing separate queries is the most straightforward and performant for your case. You can avoid messy codes by doing a loop or a similar approach. You can also do a single query with all the conditions like `{"product.name": {$in: ["apple", "mango"]}}` and handle skipping at your application layer. If you *really* need only one query, take a look at [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/). As a side note, MongodDB does not guarantee the sort order if you don't explicitly set a sort option, so you might not always skip the records you want without a sort

Answer (score -1):

Check out [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) aggregation pipeline stage

```js
db.getCollection('product_detail').aggregate([{
  $facet: {
    apple: [
      {
        $match: { "productInfo.name": "apple" } 
      },
      {
        $sort: {/* your sort condition here to ensure order */} }]
      },
      {
        $skip: 2
      }
    ],
    mango: [
      {
        $match: { "productInfo.name": "mango" }
      },
      {
        $sort: {/* your sort condition here to ensure order */} }]
      },
      {
        $skip: 2
      }
    ]
  }
}])
```

Comment: This the thing am actually trying:

Comment: db.getCollection('product_detail').find({ "productInfo.name": "mango"}).skip(2).forEach(function(doc){
    db.getCollection('product_detail').remove({_id: doc._id});
})

Comment: db.getCollection('product_detail').find({ "productInfo.name": "apple"}).skip(2).forEach(function(doc){ db.getCollection('product_detail').remove({_id: doc._id}); })

Comment: Instead of two query need one

Comment: So you want to remove the documents except the first 2 in each category?

Comment: Exactly for eg, I put 2 but it's for 1000

Comment: I think you better ask a new question specifically about removing documents

Comment: I still think it's better to do with separate queries, you can still loop over the conditions. Also, instead of finding the documents to remove, you can also find `_id` of the documents to keep. And use `.remove({ _id: { $nin: _ids } } )`